# Plugin EditorConfig - Pra que serve?

Tags: plugin, ide

Acessei o site oficial do plugin [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org), não sou muito bom de inglês então tentei traduzir pra ler e não deu muito certo, então não entendi muito bem a funcionalidade dele, ai gostaria de saber:

- Pra que ele serve?
- Como é usado?
- Qual as vantagens que eu ganho utilizando-o?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele serve para definir os padrões de edição do seu projeto. Um grande exemplo disso é a forma como seu código é identação. Vamos exemplificar com um caso onde você usa um editor que insere 4 caracteres para identar o código. Você então resolve editar o seu projeto na casa de um amigo, e o editor dele insere 6 caracteres de espaço.

O seu código ficaria algo como:

```
//parte feita na sua casa:
function codigoFeitoNoSeuEditor(){
    console.log("Fiz isso na minha casa maluca.");
}

//parte feita na casa do seu amigo:
function codigoFeitoNoEditorDoMeuAmigo(){
        console.log('Fiz isso na casa do meu amigo alienígena');
}
```

Como você pode perceber, houve uma quebra de padrão ao editar na casa do seu amigo. Para podermos fazer essa padronização que serve o editorconfig, nele você define as propriedades de edição que você utilizou, e em qualquer editor que você abra o seu projeto, teremos o mesmo comportamento.

Answer (score 1):

**Para que ele serve?**
O EditorConfig ajuda os desenvolvedores a definir e manter estilos de codificação consistentes entre diferentes editores e IDEs. Isso quer dizer que não importa qual editor você utilize, basta você e sua equipe utilizarem o plugin para que o código fique consistente.

**Como é usado?**
No site oficial na seção de **Downloads** você consegue baixar o plugin para diversos editores de códigos. O primeiro passo é baixar e instalar o plugin. Para utilizar o plugin, basta criar um arquivo `.editorconfig` na raíz do seu projeto e ajustar as configurações de acordo com sua preferência.

Deixo aqui as configurações que utilizo em quase todos os meus projetos.

root = true

[*]
   charset = utf-8
   end_of_line = lf
   indent_size = 2
   indent_style = space
   insert_final_newline = true
   trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
   max_line_length = off
   trim_trailing_whitespace = false

**Qual as vantagens que eu ganho utilizando-o?**
Desenvolvedores optam por utilizar diferentes editores de código e cada um desses editores possui suas próprias configurações para definir os padrões dos arquivos.

Um exemplo bem simples desses padrões seria: **alinhar o código utilizando espaços ou tabulações**. Só esse padrão já gera uma discussão de 01 mês entre desenvolvedores do mesmo projeto.

Imagine um desenvolvedor que goste de utilizar 04 espaços para alinhar seu código e outro que goste de utilizar 02 tabulações. Mesmo alterando apenas uma linha do código, sempre que um deles submeter esse arquivo para o versionador de códigos, todas as outras linhas sofrerão alterações também, pois a configuração de alinhamento de código deles é diferente.

Para resolver esse e outros problemas, alguém teve a brilhante ideia de desenvolver um plugin para a maioria dos editores de códigos.

**Conclusão**

Mesmo sendo um tópico bem antigo, escrevi um artigo bem interessante sobre o EditorConfig e gostaria de compartilhar com vocês.

Aqui está o link para o artigo:
https://showmethecode.com.br/2017/03/29/editor-config/

No artigo eu abordo:

- O que é EditorConfig?
- Por que utilizar EditorConfig?
- EditorConfig no VS Code
- Utilizando o EditorConfig

Comment: Agradecemos sua vontade de colaborar com a comunidade, mas talvez seja interessante ler o texto [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42) O principal problema é que, se porventura, o link da resposta deixar de existir, a resposta perde o sentido por completo. Para contornar isso, verifique junto ao conteúdo do link os principais pontos que sejam válidos à pergunta e descreve-os aqui, mantendo o link apenas como um material de apoio.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Acredito que a resposta esteja bem melhor agora. Obrigado pelo feedback.